# Is there any way to prevent default event and then fire it again with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Basically I have an anchor element, `<a href='bla..'>link</a>`

On click, I first want to do something and only once it's done I want to take the user to the page that it links to.  Something like:

```
$('a').click(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();

   //do something here

   ev.refireDefault();
});
```

Any suggestions?

### Update

My apologies! My FireFox decided to cache the previous version of JS, so nothing that I tried worked until a simple <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> solved the issue.

Comment: really a good question to ask. +1

Comment: @Ron and others who come here because of the title, is something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050538/invoke-the-default-action-of-a-specific-event-on-an-object) what you are looking for? Hopefully an answer will come

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Javascript is not multi-threaded.  It is event driven and events fire in the order in which you load them.  Therefore, if you simply leave out the `ev.preventDefault()` in your click event altogether, it won't fire the default action until the function exits.

***[See jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/fU2V6/)***

---

**EDIT per @Greg's comment:**

The only scenario in which the above is not true is with asynchronous functions.  In that scenario you would want to prevent the default action first and then in the asynchronous callback function, re-fire the default action.

Comment: +1 For you too. No idea why any of us would deserve a downvote, the answer isn't wrong.

Comment: OK, didn't mean to accuse, so I apologize. I just don't see how most of these answers are getting downvoted.

Comment: This treats the question as an X/Y problem ... but actually there is valid need to prevent an event and then refire it, such as when asynchronous functions occur within the event.

Comment: @Greg - You are correct, that would be the only reason where you may choose to prevent the default action and then refire it.  However, that's not what the OP stated he was doing, therefore the answer I gave is correct and does not deserve your down vote.  I will edit my answer to include your concern though.

Comment: @RyanSchumacher - Thank you, I renamed my jsFiddle account and thus, all links were broken.  I've updated it.

Comment: +1 for the asynchronous callback function part, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The asynchronous callback part tells me something that tbh I already know, but doesn't actually suggest a solution that doesn't involve repeating the same code that was initially running. There should be an `e.triggerDefault()` that can be fired at the end of an asynchronous call, or something similar. Moh well.

Answer (score 5):

preventDefault marks the event as handled so that when your click function exits, the default action isn't taken. If you don't call preventDefault then the default click action won't get called until your click function exits. So remove it and it'll work as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

The link will not go till after the work is done, so you can do:

```
$('a').click(function(ev){
   //do something here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

after performing your desired action why don't you just redirect it to the page by adding this line:

```
window.location = 'welcome.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

**It can be done like this:**

```
<a onclick="JavaScriptCodeHere; return true;" href='bla..'>link</a>
```

1) The **onclick** needs to be **before** the **href**.

2) **return true;**  makes sure that user will be taken to the linked page after your JS code executes. If you use `return false;` - linked itself will not work, it will just fire your JavaScript on click;

Comment: perhaps people have taken offence at the use of inline attributes for js rather than using unobtrusive event hookups